# Joint entropy of two random variables

Tags: entropy

The joint entropy is the amount of information we get when we observe X and Y at the same time, but what would happen if we don't observe them at the same time.

For example, when i toss a coin, if i got tails i will only observe the variable X, but if i got heads i will only observe the variable Y. How could i find the entropy?

Answer (score 17):

Entropy (joint entropy included), *is a property of the distribution* that a random variable follows. The available sample (and hence the timing of observation) plays no role in it.

Copying for Cover & Thomas, the joint entropy $H(X,Y)$ of two discrete random variables $X, Y,$ with joint distribution $p(x,y)$, is defined as

$$H(X,Y) = - \sum_{S_X}\sum_{S_Y}p(x,y)\log p(x,y) $$

Examine the expression: the sums are taken over *all possible values* of $X$ and $Y$, i.e. over all the values that belong to the support of each r.v. ($S_X$ and $S_Y$ respectively), irrespective of whether some of these values may not materialize or be observed in a sample. What we actually observe, or when, plays no role, in calculating entropy, and joint entropy in particular.

Turning to your specific example: The side of a coin itself can not be modeled as a random variable. A random variable maps *events* into real numbers. The side of a coin is not an event. *Observing* one of the two sides is an event.  *Not observing* a side, is an event. So let's define a random variable $X$ by "$X$ takes the value $1$ if heads is observed, $0$ otherwise". And define $Y$ by "$Y$ takes the value $1$ if tails is observed, $0$ otherwise". Assume the coin is fair. The joint distribution of these two random variables is then described by 
$$\begin{align}
P(X=1,Y=1) &= 0 \\
P(X=1,Y=0) &= 0.5 \\
P(X=0,Y=1) &= 0.5 \\
P(X=0,Y=0) &= 0
\end{align}$$

Note that the numerical mapping we chose (the zero/one values) does not play, as numbers go, any decisive part in the probabilities assigned -we could have chosen a 5/6 mapping for $X$ and a 56/89 mapping for $Y$ (or whatever) -the allocation of probabilities in the joint distribution would have been the same (it is the underlying structure of *events* that is the critical factor).
Next, as always, we consider the distribution at non-zero values, so

$$H(X,Y) = - 0.5\log(0.5) - 0.5\log(0.5) $$

and using base-2 for the logarithm we get

$$H(X,Y) = - 0.5(-1) - 0.5(-1) = 1 $$

Finally, you can easily find that the entropy of $X$ (and likewise for $Y$) is 
$$H(X) = - \sum_{S_X}p(x)\log p(x) = - 0.5(-1) - 0.5(-1) = 1 $$

So in this case $H(X,Y) = H(X) = H(Y)$. But the general expression for the decomposition of joint entropy is

$$H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y\mid X) = H(Y) + H(X\mid Y)$$

where $H(Y\mid X)$ and  $H(X\mid Y)$ are conditional entropies. Then we conclude that $H(Y\mid X) = H(X\mid Y) = 0$ in this case. The intuition is straightforward: given $X$ what has happened to $Y$ is certain (and likewise in reverse), so conditional entropy is zero.

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer with examples on a basic question!